# EntityManager can not be initialized in standalone application

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I get an exception when I try to test my code. The problem is, that the EntityManager can not been initialized.

```
private EntityManager em;

    @BeforeClass
    public void initEntityManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }
```

My persistence.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="persistence"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx\xxx;" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
            <!-- if this is true, hibernate will print (to stdout) the SQL it executes -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/spi/XATerminator
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver.resolveJtaPlatform(StandardJtaPlatformResolver.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService(JtaPlatformInitiator.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService(JtaPlatformInitiator.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2442)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2438)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1855)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at databaseconnectionTest.TestDatabaseConnection.initEntityManager(TestDatabaseConnection.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.spi.XATerminator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 46 more
```

I do not understand the exception. I am confused because the same code works perfect when I run the code on my Tomcat. Only when I try to run it as a standalone application i get this exception. At the start it stops at

```
15.07.2014 11:18:51 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
15.07.2014 11:18:52 org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

I am trying to find a solution but do not know what to do.

Hope anyone can help my.

Johannes

Comment: What does ClassNotFound mean to you? Missing jar file in your CLASSPATH. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.spi.XATerminator

Comment: OK, but I added hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager to my pom. What does I also need? And I get a NoClassDefFoundError and no ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: what have Hibernate jars got to do with javax.resource ? Hibernate is JPA (so javax.persistence), whereas javax.resource is from a JavaEE jar, such as http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/resource/javax.resource-api/1.7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClassNotFoundException is pretty clear (and ought to be familiar to anyone using Java). You don't have the specified class in your CLASSPATH, so include the jar that provides that class.

Suggest that this is likely
http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/resource/javax.resource-api/1.7/

Comment: Thank you very much, I added this to my pom and it works. My problem was, that I was confused by the NoClassDefFoundError.     <dependency>
<groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
<artifactId>connector-api</artifactId>
<version>1.5</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>