# Errors when testing a Spring web service with JUnit 4

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Hello I'm trying to test my webservice with JUnit in Spring. I have written this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/applicationContext.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration
@Transactional

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class SiteTest {

@Mock
public IBusiness siteBusiness;
@Autowired
public ManageImpl managesiteI;

List<GeographicSite> sitesJson = null;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    siteApplicationImpl=new ManageSiteImpl(siteApplicationBusiness);
}
@Test
public void testSizeOfSIte() throws ExceptionApiV2  {
try {

    when(managesiteI.geographicSitesAPIV2(Mockito.eq((Integer)10), Mockito.eq((Integer)0), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), 
            Mockito.eq("CI00002384"),Mockito.eq("CI00002394"), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), 
            Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(resultat);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERRO MOCKITO: "+e);
    }
    sitesJson=managesiteI.geographicSitesAPIV2( 10, 0, "site.id", null, "CI00002384" , "CI00002394", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null );
```

I have added the applicationContext.xml 
added all the dependencies that i thought i will need 
YET it is not working, 
first i got an error of log of this kind :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mchange.v2.log.MLog).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I managed to skip it with a static method, but i have always this error:

```
Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7a95626d: defining beans [propertyConfigurer,getActor.proxyFactory,getActor,actorBusinessImpl,manageSiteSoapProxy,manageSiteSoapProxyFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionInterceptor,transactionManager,transactionAttributes,autoProxyTransactionCreator,dataSource,siterefEntityManagerFactory,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener   [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@8fb4c62] to prepare test instance [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.SiteApplicationTest@2a53ba89]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at      org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157) ~[spring-test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
```

And i have this as caused by:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/jpaDaoContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'siterefEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/jpaDaoContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/spi/XATerminator
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527) ~[spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
```

EDIT

i have this error before teh last one :  i don't think that i have the same problem as the other question;

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error     creating bean with name 'siterefEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path     resource [META-INF/jpaDaoContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested     exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/spi/XATerminator
```

**** Edit 2***
After adding the dependency of  **javax.resource**
i got this/

```
Bean 'siterefEntityManagerFactory' of type [class   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@72ee3d51: defining beans [propertyConfigurer,getActor.proxyFactory,getActor,.....]; root of factory hierarchy
FactoryBean threw exception from getObjectType, despite the contract saying     that it should return null if the type of its object cannot be determined yet`
```

Any one have any idea ?  what am i missing ? 
if you think that i should detail something let me know, Thank you for you answers and comments

Comment: no u have edited the question to clear this point :)

Comment: Is this an error or warning? It should be there in the log.

Comment: can you post your applicationContext.xml as well.

Answer (score 0):

> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/resource/spi/XATerminator

is an indication that you are missing the jar in you classpath when running the test standalone.
You seem to be missing the javax resource API in the classpath. If you are using maven you will need to add this dependency for testing.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
 <artifactId>javax.resource-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.7</version>
 <scope>test</scope>  
</dependency>
```

Related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755303/entitymanager-can-not-be-initialized-in-standalone-application)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer actually i didn't add this dependency, and one i dont get anymore the pr evious error, instead i have this one, in the second edit